# How can I recover my gamertag?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

My Xbox 360 was recently stolen! I managed to get it back but by then the memory had been wiped clean; I want to use the same gamer tag but unfortunately the last time I was online was about a year ago. Is this possible? Can I recover my original gamertag?

Comment: The gamertag should be linked to a Microsoft Live account, so you should be able to simply retrieve it from the cloud with this account. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 4):

Gamertags are not stored on the console, so it should still be available.

To be sure you can try logging into the [xbox website](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/#fbid=lAG3RSKHMeN). There is many ways to recover your gamertag if you forgot the login information as well.

Comment: I don't think this is correct or at least should be updated with how to do it on their site as there doesn't appear to be any way on the surface

Comment: What do you mean? You'd just login using your account information as you would with any other website.

Comment: You cannot use your Gamertag only to recover your account you have to have a Microsoft Account.  Recovering a Gamertag isn't possible as you mentioned if you forgot the information.

Answer (score 1):

Press the Xbox button once the console is on and connected to an active internet connection. Choose 'recover gamertag'. Then enter your email relating to the gamertag. You will then be promted to enter the password for that email. The profile will be downloaded to the storage of your device chosen. You won't have your save games, however your achievements as of the last time you were online will still be there.

Comment: For completeness sake, on my old Xbox 360 the option I was looking for on the Xbox button menu was labelled “download profile”.